# Frequency of reactions to Covid19 vaccinations

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, covid-19-datasets

Facebook is replete with comments that 'the aftermath of the second Moderna vaccine shot was wicked', 'hit me much harder than the first' etc
Understanding that many facebook postings are unreliable sources of information, I cannot find any "reliable" sources that would inform about the frequency of short-term reactions to innoculations of the Covid 19 vaccines.

How often do recipients report "flu-like symptoms".
Is it less than 1 in 10, more than 5 in 10?

Comment: IIRC SputnikV reported 14% during trials. A reaction to the vaccine is not the same as COVID-19 disease. Many people don't realize this important fact.

Comment: There are some useful (I hope) links wtith numbers in the final 3 paras of my answer to another q https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/25382/10980 I don't know exactly what you'd qualify as "flu like" symptoms, so I'm not going to try to answer your q.

Comment: @ Fizz indeed, useful information - particularly because it was the data collected during the clinical trials and presumably well organized by the trial clinicians. Thx